# Counting names using dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, counting

I am following Dr. Charles Severance on YouTube and coding along. I am using Jupyter Notebook.

I got stuck with counting names using a dictionary. Below is the code:

```py
counts = dict()
names = {'csev','cwen','csev','zqian','cwen'}
for x in names:
    if x not in counts:
        counts[x] = 1
    else: 
        counts[x] = counts[x] + 1

print(counts)
```

As a result, I get each name only once.

I appreciate your feedback.

Have a great weekend.

Comment: Because `names` is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) which, by definition, has no duplicate entries in it :ğ

Comment: So, to make your code work, do this instead: `names = ['csev','cwen','csev','zqian','cwen']`. But using `collections.Counter` is a better technique. The approach of your YouTube source is how we used to do that in Python 1.5.2.

Comment: If you `print(names)`, you'll see each name appears indeed once.

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections
counted_names = collections.Counter(names)
print(counted_names,dict(counted_names))
```

is how someone would normally do this

... but that still wont solve your problem... because sets will not have duplicates

change to `names = ['csev','cwen','csev','zqian','cwen']` and your solution and this alternative will work as expected

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. May I ask, why? Because for dictionary we use curly brackets, and for list square brackets?

Comment: sets do not have duplicates ... `{1,2,3}` is a set as denoted by curly braces

Comment: @VeraKatic you should have tried `print(type(names))` and you would have figured out the answer yourself. Sets in python are also represented by curly braces. Dictionaries have `key:value` pairs, while sets have just items, the same as lists. But in a set, you cannot add the same value more than once. If you do, it will not be added. For example, `{'csev','cwen','csev','zqian','cwen'}` is equal to `{'csev','cwen','zquian'}`, because python removes the duplicates in a set. But in a list, you can have duplicates, so `['csev','cwen','csev','zqian','cwen']` doesn't change itself.